# Pygame: How to deform a surface perspectively without OpenGL

Tags: python, 2d, pygame

I'm making a 2D game with Pygame.
There is a surface which I'd like to deform perspectively (without using OpenGL)
Has anyone an idea on how to accomplish that?

Here's a picture showing the original image and one example of what I mean by deform perspectively.

[image]

Comment: do you only need to display it deformed like that or does it need to be a variable amount so that it can be changed to almost anything by the user?

Comment: It needs to be a variable amount.

Comment: This is directly answered in your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177744/how-does-perspective-transformation-work-in-pil/14178717#14178717.