# Image perspective transform using Pillow

Tags: python, image, transform, python-imaging-library

I tried to draw bounding box of text on a image.The image 
is perspective-transformed with a given set of coefficients. The coordinates of text before transformation is known, and I want to calculate the coordinates of text after transformation.

To my understanding if I apply perspective transformation with the coefficients used in image transform to the text coordinates, I will get the resulting coordinates of the text after transformation. However, the text does not appear on the place it is supposed to be.

See the following graphs 
[image: graph before transformation]

The smaller white box bounds the text well because I know the coordinates of the text.

[image: graph after transformation]

The smaller white box is not bounding the text because of some error during transforming the coordinates.

I follow the documentation [reference for coefficients of perspective transformation](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm) 
and find the coefficients of image transformation using the following code:[origin of the code is from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177744/how-does-perspective-transformation-work-in-pil/24088499#24088499)

```
def find_coeffs(pa, pb):
    '''
    find the coefficients for perspective transform. 

    parameters:
        pa : verticies in the resulting plane
        pb : verticies in the current plane

    retrun:
        coeffs : 8- tuple
          coefficents for PIL perspective transform
    '''
    matrix = []
    for p1, p2 in zip(pa, pb):
        matrix.append([p1[0], p1[1], 1, 0, 0, 0, -p2[0]*p1[0], -p2[0]*p1[1]])
        matrix.append([0, 0, 0, p1[0], p1[1], 1, -p2[1]*p1[0], -p2[1]*p1[1]])

    A = np.matrix(matrix, dtype=np.float)
    B = np.array(pb).reshape(8)
    res = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(A.T * A) * A.T, B)
    return np.array(res).reshape(8)
```

My code for text bounding box transformation:

```
    # perspective transformation
    a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h = coeffs
    # return two vertices defining the bounding box

    new_x0 = float(a * new_x0 - b * new_y0 + c) / float(g * new_x0 + h * new_y0 + 1)
    new_y0 = float(d * new_x0 + e * new_y0 + f) / float(g * new_x0 + h * new_y0 + 1)
    new_x1 = float(a * new_x1 - b * new_y1 + c) / float(g * new_x1 + h * new_y1 + 1)
    new_y1 = float(d * new_x1 + e * new_y1 + f) / float(g * new_x1 + h * new_y1 + 1)
```

I also went to Pillow Github, but I could not find the source code where perspective transformation is defined.

Some more info about the math of perspective transformation. [The Geometry of Perspective Drawing on the Computer](https://www.math.utah.edu/~treiberg/Perspect/Perspect.htm)

Thanks.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean. Are you trying to transform the second image or do you want to transform the white boxes you've drawn to fit the image/sign?

Comment: I want to transform the smaller white box in the second graph so that is bounds the text.

Answer (score 1):

To compute the new point after a transformation you should get the coefficients from A -> B not from B -> A, which is the standard from PIL library. As example:

```
# A1, B1 ... are points
# direct transform
coefs = find_coefs([B1, B2, B3, B4], [A1, A2, A3, A4])

# inverse transform
coefs_inv = find_coefs([A1, A2, A3, A4], [B1, B2, B3, B4])
```

You call the `image.transform()` function using the `coefs_inv` but calculate the new point using `coefs` to get something like this:

```
img = image.transform(((1500,800)),
                      method=Image.PERSPECTIVE,
                      data=coefs_inv)

a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h = coefs

old_p1 = [50, 100]
x,y = old_p1
new_x = (a * x + b * y + c) / (g * x + h * y + 1)
new_y = (d * x + e * y + f) / (g * x + h * y + 1)
new_p1 = (int(new_x),int(new_y))

old_p2 = [400, 500]
x,y = old_p2
new_x = (a * x + b * y + c) / (g * x + h * y + 1)
new_y = (d * x + e * y + f) / (g * x + h * y + 1)
new_p2 = (int(new_x),int(new_y))
```

[image: PILperspective]

Full code below:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def find_coefs(original_coords, warped_coords):
        matrix = []
        for p1, p2 in zip(original_coords, warped_coords):
            matrix.append([p1[0], p1[1], 1, 0, 0, 0, -p2[0]*p1[0], -p2[0]*p1[1]])
            matrix.append([0, 0, 0, p1[0], p1[1], 1, -p2[1]*p1[0], -p2[1]*p1[1]])

        A = np.matrix(matrix, dtype=np.float)
        B = np.array(warped_coords).reshape(8)

        res = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(A.T * A) * A.T, B)
        return np.array(res).reshape(8)


coefs = find_coefs(
                  [(867,652), (1020,580), (1206,666), (1057,757)],
                  [(700,732), (869,754), (906,916), (712,906)]
                  )

coefs_inv = find_coefs(
                  [(700,732), (869,754), (906,916), (712,906)],
                  [(867,652), (1020,580), (1206,666), (1057,757)]
                  )

image = Image.open('sample.png')

img = image.transform(((1500,800)),
                      method=Image.PERSPECTIVE,
                      data=coefs_inv)

a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h = coefs

old_p1 = [50, 100]
x,y = old_p1
new_x = (a * x + b * y + c) / (g * x + h * y + 1)
new_y = (d * x + e * y + f) / (g * x + h * y + 1)
new_p1 = (int(new_x),int(new_y))

old_p2 = [400, 500]
x,y = old_p2
new_x = (a * x + b * y + c) / (g * x + h * y + 1)
new_y = (d * x + e * y + f) / (g * x + h * y + 1)
new_p2 = (int(new_x),int(new_y))



plt.figure()
plt.imshow(image)
plt.scatter([old_p1[0], old_p2[0]],[old_p1[1], old_p2[1]]  , s=150, marker='.', c='b')
plt.show()


plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img)
plt.scatter([new_p1[0], new_p2[0]],[new_p1[1], new_p2[1]]  , s=150, marker='.', c='r')

plt.show()
```