# Upscaling while perspective transformation with PIL

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I use the image transformation function of PIL according to [How does perspective transformation work in PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177744/how-does-perspective-transformation-work-in-pil), which works fine. The only thing which does not work is increasing the resolution of the resulting image.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

imgData=plt.imread('img.jpg')
print imgData.shape

img=Image.fromarray(imgData)
plt.imshow(img)
```

[image: original image]

the transformation without increasing the resolution works fine

```
def find_coeffs(pa, pb):
    matrix = []
    for p1, p2 in zip(pa, pb):
        matrix.append([p1[0], p1[1], 1, 0, 0, 0, -p2[0]*p1[0], -p2[0]*p1[1]])
        matrix.append([0, 0, 0, p1[0], p1[1], 1, -p2[1]*p1[0], -p2[1]*p1[1]])

    A = np.matrix(matrix, dtype=np.float)
    B = np.array(pb).reshape(8)

    res = np.linalg.solve(A, B)
    return np.array(res).reshape(8)

coeffs = find_coeffs(
        [(0, 0), (256, 0), (256, 256), (0, 256)],
        [(0, 0), (256, 0), (100, 200), (10, 200)])

imgNew=img.transform((256, 256), Image.PERSPECTIVE, coeffs,
        Image.BICUBIC)
plt.imshow(imgNew)
```

[image: transformed image without increasing the resolution]

But if I want to increase the resolution there is some strange behaviour of PIL - the image is not reszized to the resulting canvas size

```
imgNew2=img.transform((1500, 1500), Image.PERSPECTIVE, coeffs,
    Image.BICUBIC)
imgNew2.save('imgNew2.jpg')
plt.imshow(imgNew2)
```

[image: transformed image with increased resolution]

Any ideas how to solve this without resizing the image with PIL.Image.resize before tranforming it?

Comment: Every pixel of the original image ended up somewhere in that final image, controlled by your transform matrix - where do you expect any further pixel data to come from, to make it any bigger?  If you just wanted a bigger version of your 256x256 result, you need to change the matrix accordingly - I think changing all the 256s to 1500s in `pa` would do it.

Comment: OK got it. That makes sense and also works. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177744/how-does-perspective-transformation-work-in-pil
this will solve your problem.