# Python - Make Text Slanted with PIL Library

Tags: python-3.x, fonts, python-imaging-library, affinetransform

I'd like to control the slantiness (italic) of a text according a given **degree** and **direction (left or right tilt)** similar as presented in the image below:

[image]

I have stumble upon this great answer: [How does perspective transformation work in PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177744/how-does-perspective-transformation-work-in-pil), played with the code, and read the documentation of `AFFINE` but it's still isn't clear enough for me.

Can someone please explain me (mathematic and logic wise), how can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: I've added a mirror to the broken link in the referenced answer. Does that help?

Comment: @Caramiriel Thank you, but the mirror is a bit too technical for me,
I just know in context of the transform function:
The data is a 6-tuple ( a, b, c, d, e, f) which contain the first two rows from an affine transform matrix. For each pixel (x,y)
in the output image, the new value is taken from a position (ax+by+c,dx+ey+f) in the input image, rounded to nearest pixel.

Comment: A great explanation I found is written here in the following document:
https://people.cs.clemson.edu/~dhouse/courses/401/notes/affines-matrices.pdf

Answer (score 4):

To generate some text we can use any method, here I am using ImageFont to get a black and white mask.

```
def generate_text(text):
    fnt = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 72)
    img = Image.new('1', fnt.getsize(text))
    mask = [x for x in fnt.getmask(text, mode='1')]
    img.putdata(mask)
    img = img.convert('RGB')
    return img
```

[image]

Then, I would like to add padding on the left and right because we will be shearing the text horizontally.

```
def add_border(img, width):
    new = Image.new('RGB', (img.width + 2 * width, img.height), (0, 0, 0))
    new.paste(img, (width, 0))
    return new
```

[image]

Finally, I will use an affine transformation using the `b` value, which if you look a the formula, it is the coefficient of `y` that will be added to `x`. So, a larger `b` will shear horizontally more. In this case I am using `2`.

```
def shear(img, shear):
    shear = img.transform(img.size, Image.AFFINE, (1, shear, 0, 0, 1, 0))
    return shear
```

[image]

The calling code:

```
img = generate_text('test')
img = add_border(img, 200)
img = shear(img, 2)
```

Comment: Hello. How to modify the shear function to have white padding?

Comment: @alyssaeliyah I don't understand. Where would the white padding appear?