# Flip card animation in Python

Tags: python, animation, graphics

I have two still images, one for the front of a card, and one for the back. I want to create a video animation of the card flipping over and showing the back, similar to [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/auroratide/pen/WNmmQzP) that does it in CSS and JavaScript.

I am sure that it's possible in Python and a library like PIL, Pyglet or Pygame (e.g., with [perspective drawing in PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177744/how-does-perspective-transformation-work-in-pil)), but I cannot find it with a search for `python pil|pyglet|pygame code flip card animation`. It seems general enough that I think someone has needed this before.

Has anyone faced this problem and has code that animates a card turning over?

Comment: you picked the wrong library. opencv is for *computer **vision***, not for drawing. it can draw but that is not its purpose. if you want to draw, there are libraries for ***that*** purpose. -- you were never gonna find anything with such a specific search query. basic programming. break the problem down into steps.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thank you, I edited the question to remove OpenCV. I found that PIL, Pyglet or Pygame could help, but couldn't find a function or code for this either.